# Bash script to read from a file and save the information in an array?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read from a file that has host IPs written in it and save it in an array. So far I have tried this:

```
Host=`cat /home/hp3385/Desktop/config | egrep '^Host' | awk '{print $2}'`
```

But I don't think that it saves the information in an array. What is the type of the variable 'Host'? If it's not an array how can I convert it into one?
This is a sample data from the file `/home/hp3385/Desktop/config`:

```
############# Server1 #################
Host 8.8.8.8
Hostname google

############# Server2 ################
Host 8.8.4.4
Hostname google
```

The expected output is:
`a=($'8.8.8.8' $'8.8.4.4')`

Comment: Use `mapfile` to create an array. If you want an answer, you should specify the expected array, for instance `a=(8.8.8.8 google 8.8.8.8 google)` or `a=($'8.8.8.8\ngoogle' $'8.8.8.8\ngoogle')` or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
myarray=()
while read -r line; do
  if echo "$line" | grep -q 'Host '; then
     myarray+=($(echo "$line" | awk '/^Host/ {print $2}'))
  fi
done < /home/hp3385/Desktop/config
```

Comment: this gave me an error `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` on `myarray=()`

Comment: Please make sure you use **bash**

Comment: `for a in $myarray
do
 if [ "$a" == "8.8.8.8" ] ;  then
  echo $a
 fi
done` @funkyjelly why does this doesn't work though? `myarray` is an array then I guess this shoud print out the IP.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring an array:

```
ARRAY=(0 1 2 3 4 5)
```

So your array can be declared like this:

```
HOSTS=($(awk '/^Host/ {print $2}' YOUR_FILE))
```

If you want to know the amount of values in your array:

```
echo ${#HOSTS[*]}
```

To get an output of all values in your array (credit goes to [triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)):

```
printf '%s\n' "${HOSTS[@]}"
```

Comment: Your `for` loop will break if the array contains elements which require quoting, and is needlessly complex anyway. Simply `printf '%s\n' "${HOSTS[@]}"` will do.

Comment: or a simpler for loop `for i in ${HOSTS[@]}; do echo $i; done`